# How to use setState inside callback: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is the code that I used to set the state.

```
handleAddNewQuiz(event){
    this.quiz = new Quiz(this.db, this.newQuizName, function(err, affected, value){
        if(!err){
            this.setState( { quiz : value});  // ERROR: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Even though the database is created successfully, I cannot call `this.setState`, as it's always undefined.

I tried:

```
self = this;

handleAddNewQuiz(event){
    this.quiz = new Quiz(this.db, this.newQuizName, function(err, affected, value){
        if(!err){
            self.setState( { quiz : value});  // ERROR: self.setState is not a function
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

But it still fails, Also tried with `a = this`, and using `a.setState`, but still no luck.

How can I solve this?

Comment: use ()=> {} instead using function(){}.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to bind correct `this` (class context) with callback method, then only you will be able to access the class properties and methods.

---

**Possible Solutions:**

**1-** Use [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), like this:

```
 handleAddNewQuiz(event){
        this.quiz = new Quiz(this.db, this.newQuizName, (err, affected, value) => {
            if(!err){
                this.setState( { quiz : value}); 
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    };
```

**2-** Or use `.bind(this)` with `callback method`, like this:

```
handleAddNewQuiz(event){
    this.quiz = new Quiz(this.db, this.newQuizName, function(err, affected, value){
        if(!err){
            this.setState( { quiz : value});  
        }
    }.bind(this));
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

The way you are using will also work, save the reference of `this` inside the `handleAddNewQuiz` method, like this way:

```
handleAddNewQuiz(event){
    let self = this;    //here save the reference of this
    this.quiz = new Quiz(this.db, this.newQuizName, function(err, affected, value){
        if(!err){
            self.setState( { quiz : value});  
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: i would rather pick 1 and 2 variant cuz due to unnecessary usage of one more variable is not so good example

Comment: @ddeadlink, i also used to prefer 1st and 2nd way, in 3rd way, i suggested him how to save reference in a third variable like he is using in his ques.

Comment: tottaly understand what you were leading to,  so i upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

Mayank's answer is correct.. 
Alternatively you can use 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators

and use the @autobind decorator before the function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)