# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, calendar

I'm trying to pass returend argument from firebase to a state param but I'm getting this error:

```
App.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null
```

I would like to pass "snapshot" array into "calendars" and then retrieve calendars value like "calendars.summary" or "calendars.date" (I know how to do that, but the problem is that I can't assign snapshot to calendars).

```
componentDidMount() {
    //setInterval(() => start(this.state.gapi,true), 30000);
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var urlRef = rootRef.child("testCalendar/calendars");
urlRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key+": "+child.child("summary").val());


  });
  this.setState({
      calendars: snapshot
    });
});
    }
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

**UPDATE**
After Mayank Shukla'comment, I'm able to pass correctly "snapshot" by doing:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //setInterval(() => start(this.state.gapi,true), 30000);
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var urlRef = rootRef.child("testCalendar/calendars");
urlRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key+": "+child.child("summary").val());

  });
  this.setState({
      calendars: snapshot
    });
}.bind(this));
    }
```

or

```
componentDidMount() {
    //setInterval(() => start(this.state.gapi,true), 30000);
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var urlRef = rootRef.child("testCalendar/calendars");
urlRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key+": "+child.child("summary").val());

  });
  this.setState({
      calendars: snapshot
    });
});
    }
```

But now i have this problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.state.calendars.map is not a function
```

on this function:

```
_getCalendarsList(){
     var d = new Date();

    return this.state.calendars.map((calend) => {
    return (
      <Calendar 
      {...calend} 
      key={d.getTime()} />

      )
    });
  }
```

Comment: it's a binding issue, use arrow function: `urlRef.once("value", (snapshot) =>  {` to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot setState inside callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275845/cannot-setstate-inside-callback)

Comment: @MayankShukla ok it works but now i have this problem: "TypeError: this.state.calendars.map is not a function" maybe couse of snapshot is not an iterable??

Comment: _getCalendarsList(){
     var d = new Date();
    
    return this.state.calendars.map((calend) => {
    return (
      <Calendar 
      {...calend} 
      key={d.getTime()} />

      )
    });
  }

Comment: this.state.calendar should be an array to map over it, console.log(this.state.calendar ) in the function ,to see what object you get

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it returns "[]" after 'this.setState({
      calendars: snapshot
    });'. snaphost is not assigned to calendars, is it?

Comment: What is the initial value that you assign to state calendar

Answer (score 0):

To use `map`on any variable, that variable needs to be an `array`, you are fetching the data in `componentDidMount` method, it will get called after the initial rendering, so make sure the initial value of `calendars` in state should be `[]`, like this:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
      calendars: [],
      ....
   }
}
```

Or put the check before using `map`, if that is not an `array` then `return null`, like this:

```
_getCalendarsList(){
    if(!Array.isArray(this.state.calendars))
       return null;

    var d = new Date();

    return this.state.calendars.map((calend) => {
        return (
             <Calendar 
                  {...calend} 
                  key={d.getTime()} 
             />

        )
    });
}
```

Comment: yep, in constructor i already had "this.state = {
      calendars: [],
      gapi: null
    }"

Comment: that means, data that you are fetching is not an array, do `console.log(snapshot)` once you get the response and check, also show the result me.

Comment: returns a kind of tree: V {A: O, V: U, g: rc}. I made a screenshot: [link](https://ibb.co/h9VhmQ)

Comment: its not an array, it's object, on which field you want to use the map on V or on V.A or V.V or V.g ?