# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have pasted my whole there is very minor problem in this code but I'm not able to resolve the problem. Please review this code.

It's showing following error while consoling:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined reactjs

Code:

```js
export class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChangeforSignUp = this.handleChangeforSignUp.bind(this);
    this.createNewUserWithEmailPassword = this.createNewUserWithEmailPassword.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      sign_up_details: {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmpassword: "",
        notification: ""
      }
    };
  }
  
    createNewUserWithEmailPassword(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if((this.state.sign_up_details.password !== "") && (this.state.sign_up_details.confirmpassword !== "")){
      if(this.state.sign_up_details.password === this.state.sign_up_details.confirmpassword){
        let updateNotification = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {notification: "Password matched"});
        this.setState({
          sign_up_details: updateNotification
        });

        app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.sign_up_details.email, this.state.sign_up_details.password)
        .catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          let errorCode = error.code;
          console.log(errorCode);
          let errorMessage = error.message;
          if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
            let notify = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {notification: errorMessage});      
            this.setState({
              sign_up_details: notify
            });
          } else {
            // alert(errorMessage);
            let notify = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {notification: errorMessage});      
            this.setState({
              sign_up_details: notify
            },
            () => {
              console.log(this.state.sign_up_details);
            } );
          }
          console.log(error);
        }).then(
          function(onResolve, onReject){
            console.log(onResolve);
            console.log(onReject);
          }
        );

      }else{
        let notify = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {notification: "Password not matched"});
        this.setState({
          sign_up_details: notify
        });
      }
    }
  }
  
    handleChangeforSignUp(event){
    // console.log(event);
    const  target = event.target;
    let emailInput = "";
    let passwordInput = "";
    let confirmpasswordInput = "";
      
    if(target.type === 'email'){
      emailInput = target.value;
      let updateEmail = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {email: emailInput});
      this.setState({
        sign_up_details: updateEmail
      });

    }

    if(target.type === 'password' && target.name === 'password'){
      passwordInput = target.value;
      let updatePassword = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {password: passwordInput});      
      this.setState({
        sign_up_details: updatePassword
      });
    }

    if(target.type === 'password' && target.name === 'confirmpassword'){
      confirmpasswordInput = target.value;
      let updateConfirmpassword = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {confirmpassword: confirmpasswordInput});
      this.setState({
        sign_up_details: updateConfirmpassword
      });
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } }
    //  const { from } = this.props.history.location || { from: { pathname: '/' } }
    
    if (this.state.redirect === true) {
      return <Redirect to={from} />
    }

    return (
        <div id="register" class="container tab-pane fade animated fadeIn">
          <form onSubmit={this.createNewUserWithEmailPassword} className="formfield" ref={(form) => { this.signupForm = form }} method="post">
              <h1 className="text-center login-heading pt-2 pb-4"><i className="fa fa-pencil fa-lg mx-2" ></i> Register</h1>
              {/* <input value={this.state.sign_up_details.name} onChange={this.handleChangeforSignUp}  className="form-control input mb-2" name="name" type="text" placeholder="John Doe" />               */}
              <input value={this.state.sign_up_details.email} onChange={this.handleChangeforSignUp}  className="form-control input mb-2" name="email" type="email" placeholder="john.doe@jd.com" />
              <input value={this.state.sign_up_details.password} onChange={this.handleChangeforSignUp}  className="form-control input mb-2" name="password" type="password" placeholder="*******" />
              <input value={this.state.sign_up_details.confirmpassword} onChange={this.handleChangeforSignUp}  className="form-control input mb-2" name="confirmpassword" type="password" placeholder="*******" />              
              <p className="text_ter text_pink">{this.state.sign_up_details.notification !== "" ? this.state.sign_up_details.notification : ""}</p>
              <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block p-2 mt-4 mb-2" value="Log In"></input>
          </form>
        </div>

     
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Login/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"><div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVIK3.png)

Comment: On which line are you facing this issue? Make sure your functions that are making use of `this` are bound to the class.

Comment: Once inside the `catch`, your `this` does not refer to the component class, so it does not have any state. You should declare it outside the async request, something like `let self = this.state` and then use it.

Comment: check this answer [How to do setState inside callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275845/how-to-do-setstate-inside-callback-reactjs)

Comment: The console showing error on `else {
            // alert(errorMessage);
            let notify = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {notification: errorMessage});      
            this.setState({
              sign_up_details: notify
            },
            () => {
              console.log(this.state.sign_up_details);
            } );` in this block of **code**

Comment: @Ionut Thanks, trying

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks all geeks, the problem was in promises. I was using tradition js functions instead of ES7 arrows functions. I just used arrows function instead of js functions in promises callback everything has resolved.

Comment: **Here is the piece of edited code** from the question.

Comment: `app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.sign_up_details.email, this.state.sign_up_details.password).catch((error) => {let errorCode = error.code; if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {weakPass = error.message;let notify = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {notification: weakPass}); this.setState({sign_up_details: notify});} else {genericError = error.message;let notify = Object.assign({}, this.state.sign_up_details, {notification: genericError});this.setState({sign_up_details: notify});}`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using react-router (which gives you the `Redirect` component for example) but it's never imported or included anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, But redirection is not the part of this error. Something is wrong in the `this.state.signup_details`. Its just a piece of code of a complete application. @timotgl

Comment: May I set the state of particular class in promises? @timotgl

Comment: @kropani Try changing the methods so that they have the component in scope with `this.`: `createNewUserWithEmailPassword = (event) => {}` Same for the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

So this error is the equivalent to you having written `undefined.state`

Take a look at your event handlers such as `handleChangeForSignup()` which you are using bad practice in your naming, its not completely camel case, you have `handleChangeforSignup()`.

Specifically relating to this error though, look at `createNewUserWithEmailPassword()`.

Did you try testing it out first by doing:

```
createNewUserWithEmailPassword(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.sign_up_details);
  }
```

Do you see another problem here? Again, naming convention. You need this event handler to do one thing at a time. You see how the console log I added would not work? It would only check for email, but if you would have done this first, you know take it one step at a time and test your code along the way, you probably would have gotten this error earlier.

JavaScript thinks that inside your `createNewUserWithEmailPassword()` is not equal to `this`, but instead `this` is equal to undefined.

You need to review what the `this` keyword is used for inside of a class and how the value of `this` is determined inside a function.

Your `Login` instance should have a few different properties such as `state`, `render()` and `createNewUserWithEmailPassword()`.

You should be able to reference the keyword `this` which is a reference back to the class itself.

So you are saying give me the reference to the instance of `Login` that I am writing code inside of. That should give you access to `state`, `render()` and `createNewUserWithEmailPassword()`.

I would clean up the code a bit like so:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
      sign_up_details: {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmpassword: "",
        notification: ""
      }
    };
  }
```

unless you are doing `import React, { Component } from 'react';` but you did not include that in your post so I did `React.Component`.

So why is `this` is going wrong inside of `createNewUserWithEmailPassword()`?

To understand that, we need a good idea of how the value of `this` is determined inside a function.

```
class Car {
    setDriveSound(){
    this.sound = sound;
  }

  drive() {
    return this.sound;
  }
}
```

This is just a dummy class that allows us to set a value and later return that value.

```
class Car {
    setDriveSound(sound){
    this.sound = sound;
  }

  drive() {
    return this.sound;
  }
}

const car = new Car();
car.setDriveSound('vroom');
car.drive();
```

This will output `vroom`.

So here is an important rule to understand. Whenever we want to figure out what the value of `this` is going to be inside of a method on a class, don't look at the method itself, look at where you called the method.

In my example above, we look at `car.drive();`.

We find the function name, in this case `drive()`, we look to the dot to the left of the function, and look at the variable that is referenced inside.

So `this` from `return this.sound;` inside the `drive()` method is going to be equal to the `car` variable inside the `Car` class.

So, don't look at the function, look at where the function is called. What is to the left of dot when the function gets called.

So when `drive()` is called on `car`, `this` becomes equal to the instance of the `car`.

I will create an object called `truck` and rip off the `drive()` function from the instance of `car` and assign it to the truck object:

```
const truck = {
    sound: "honk_honk",
    driveMyTruck: car.drive
}

truck.driveMyTruck();
```

This will return `honk_honk` because `truck` is equal to `this` inside the `drive()` function.

The latter is the equivalent to doing:

```
drive() {
  return truck.sound;
}
```

Lets apply the above so what is going on in your case.

Now if I try this:

```
const drive = car.drive;

drive();
```

Now I would get `Cannot read property 'sound' of undefined`.

So when the callback is passed down the form element at some point in time we are going to call `createNewUserWithEmailPassword()` and when it gets invoked, there is no `Login` `createNewUserWithEmailPassword`.

This example here:

```
class Car {
    setDriveSound(sound){
    this.sound = sound;
  }

  drive() {
    return this.sound;
  }
}

const car = new Car();
car.setDriveSound('vroom');

const drive = car.drive;

drive();
```

is exactly what you did, or what you have going on.

This may still be confusing, it's not an easy concept to understand, I get this type of error message very frequently as well.

So how would you apply what I just explained?

There are several ways to solve your problem.

Now, you added a `constructor(props)` method with `super(props)` because it extends `React.Component` and you did `this.createNewUserWithEmailPassword = this.createNewUserWithEmailPassword.bind(this);`

This should have produced a new version of the function and it should have been fixed with the correct value of `this`, but it didn't solve it.

So try this:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
      sign_up_details: {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmpassword: "",
        notification: ""
      }
    };

    createNewUserWithEmailPassword = (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();

       console.log(this.state.sign_up_details);
    }
 }
```